# Почему не подключается Monaco editor в Electron.js?

Tags: javascript, electron

Пытаюсь подключить monaco в electron.js, кстановил модуль:

```
npm install monaco-editor
```

Далее на клиенте пишу

```js
const { createMonaco } = require("monaco-editor");
const h_div = document.querySelector("editor");
// Создаем экземпляр Monaco Editor
const editor = createMonaco(h_div, {
    value: 'console.log("Hello, Monaco!");', // начальное содержимое
    language: 'javascript', // язык
});

// Можно также добавить обработчики событий для редактора
editor.onDidChangeModelContent((event) => {
    // Обработка изменений в тексте редактора
    console.log(editor.getValue());
});
```

Но получаю постоянно ошибку Cannot find module 'monaco-editor', хотя библиотека установлена
Уже три часа мучаюсь пытаюсь все варианты подключения сделать ничего не работает
чат гпт предложил такой вариант:

```js
<div id="editor-container"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor"></script>
<script>
  require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor/min/vs' } });
  require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
    const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor-container'), {
      value: 'console.log("Hello, Monaco!");',
      language: 'javascript',
    });
  });
</script>
```

Ошибок нет но и ничего не происходит, то есть в require(['vs/editor/editor.main'] он вообще не заходит